4.1 Shader ignored in render
I'm following the CG Cookie HUMAN course, which was created with Blender 2.93.  In the Skin Material I section we're supposed to add subsurface scattering to our guy.  That facility has changed significantly between 2.93 and 4.1 so I tried to figure out the new method.  The weird thing is that in materials preview the guy looks fine, but in render preview mode and in render everything specified by the shader nodes disappears.  I'm fairly new to Blender but have learned that there are a lot of hidden ways to turn something off, so figured I probably flipped a switch somewhere that means "ignore shader in render".  To verify that I got the shader right I made a very simple blend file of Suzanne and used the exact same shader in my homework for the course, and the results are very different.  Suzanne came out as expected but my homework render shows none of the effects specified by the shader.  I've checked everything I can think of and expect to feel really stupid when somebody points out what I overlooked   Here are the blend files: Suzanne Homework

That's a paid-for course so we don't have access to the tutorial in the 'Skin Material' link you've put in your question.

I think the problem is in material override:

This replaces all materials in the view layer by the selected one. Remove it.

Hi. Crantisz.. is this based on the share? I'm only asking to see whether I need to nudge OP to make a smaller download.

Yep, it is a screenshot from the file

Cheers :)  No need to bother Walt.. this will be it, surely.

The material override was indeed the problem.  Thank you so much Crantisz!

Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers
